# How to get visual studio code and visual studio 2022 to match code formatting

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

It seems like the default settings for code formatting (javascript, typescript, CSS, etc.) are different between visual studio code and visual studio 2022. What is the best way to get these to have the same formatting rules & settings?